# Under what condition an endpoint can be under switch- off state in WSO2 esb

Tags: wso2-esb

I am a beginner in WSO2 ESB and while monitoring I can see some endpoints are in switch-off state then I have to turn it on manually. What makes them to go into switch off state . Are they suspended or is it because of some fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

The switch off functionality allows endpoints to be temporarily deactivated to avoid performance issues that result from heavy traffic.

Answer (score 0):

@RachnaSingh, Hi, Below attached link contain some answers to your question, please refer the link [Switching On and Off](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/Switching+On+and+Off)